# JobScheduler not working on (not pure) Android

Tags: android, background-process, kill-process, android-jobscheduler, oneplusthree

I am using JobScheduler to run a periodic background service on my app.
It turns out that it is working properly on a Nexus phone (android 8.1), but it is not working on a OnePlus 3t (android 8.0, OxygenOS 5.0.1) nor in a Huawei P8 when the app is killed.

The thing is that OxygenOS, for example, kills most of the background processes when the app is terminated.

I've changed Deep Clear to Normal Clear in "Settings > Advanced > Recent app management" and it works fine.

My question: is there a way to make the JobScheduler run without the user having to change anything on his device?

If not, can I find a list of devices with custom android that will behave in the same way as my OnePlus or the Huawei?

Thanks :)